# Как обработать ошибку RetryAfter в Aiogram

Tags: python, telegram, aiogram

После отправки юзером 30 CallBackQuery и отправки ботом 30 сообщений, вылетает следующая ошибка:

```
aiogram.utils.exceptions.RetryAfter: Flood control exceeded. Retry in 198 seconds.
```

Как можно принимать эту ошибку, и отправлять пользователю сообщение, в котором будет появляться текст с просьбой подождать {`время`} и не флудить?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Для этого у aiogram есть отдельный фильтр, Вам нужно передать в параметры исключения, которые должны быть обработаны:

```py
@dp.errors_handler(exception=exceptions.RetryAfter)
async def exception_handler(update: types.Update, exception: exceptions.RetryAfter):
    # Do something
    return True
```