# Как импортировать исключения из aiogram и отловить их?

Tags: python, telegram-bot, aiogram-3.x

Есть бот на aiogram 3.0.0b8 который должен рассылать сообщения.
Но у тг есть же ограничения.. и надо их отловить, не упасть, подождать и снова попробовать отправить

Попробовал так:

```
from aiogram.utils import exceptions
...
try:
   await bot.send_message(user.user_id_tg, text=user.success_msg, reply_markup=keyboard_3)
except exceptions.RetryAfter as e:
   await asyncio.sleep(e.timeout)
   await bot.send_message(user.user_id_tg, text=user.success_msg, reply_markup=keyboard_3)
```

Но интерпретатор ругается: **ImportError: cannot import name 'exceptions' from 'aiogram.utils'**

Попробовал так импортировать:

```
from aiogram.utils.exceptions import RetryAfter
```

И тоже ругается: **ImportError: cannot import name 'exceptions' from 'aiogram.utils'**

Этоm код выполняется функцией по расписанию

```
# Сообщения по расписанию
scheduler = AsyncIOScheduler(timezone="Europe/Moscow")
scheduler.add_job(time_msg.start_time_push, trigger='cron', hour=16,
                  minute=48, start_date=datetime.now(),
                  kwargs={'bot': bot})
scheduler.start()
```

В документации Aiogram по этому вопросу ничего не понял, если честно)
Импорты нагуглил...

Comment: Кстати ещё это посмотрите https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1326829/%D0%9A%D0%B0%D0%BA-%D0%BE%D0%B1%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%B1%D0%BE%D1%82%D0%B0%D1%82%D1%8C-%D0%BE%D1%88%D0%B8%D0%B1%D0%BA%D1%83-retryafter-%D0%B2-aiogram

Comment: спасибо-спасибо!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
from aiogram.exceptions import AiogramError
...

try:
    ...
except AiogramError as E:
    print(E)
    ...
...
```

AiogramError - это базовое исключение, от которого наследуются все остальные.

[Документация](https://docs.aiogram.dev/en/latest/dispatcher/errors.html#:%7E:text=aiogram.exceptions.AiogramError)

Само собой, такое исключение следует использовать тогда и только тогда, когда вы хотите отлавливать **все** исключения, которые могут быть вызваны aiogram'ом. Если же ваша цель отлавливать только некоторый список, то следует указать его явно, например

```
from aiogram.exceptions import *
...
try:
    ...
except (TelegramServerError, TelegramRetryAfter):
    ...
...
```

Comment: Спасибо огромное!